# SPM dependency in different projects

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have iOS workspace of two projects:

`Core` - is a project with framework. Also it has `RxSwift` dependency via swift package manager.

`App` - is an application that has `Core.framework` as embed dependency and `RxSwift` as swift package manager dependency.

I get these warnings on app running:

```
objc[8296]: Class _TtC7RxSwiftP33_AB3B9E8806A71B46FB498A7594F5E0D919AnonymousDisposable is implemented in both /Users/andrey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dypyskhwoifkwagjjvtjblqppdnd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Core.framework/Core (0x10e092400) and /Users/andrey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/53D234F9-F917-46BA-B376-F28BA905EE9D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D4C69694-8515-44CF-B077-0CB3256D1F84/App.app/App (0x10bf95430). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

But if I try to access `MainScheduler.instance` that is a static variable I will get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash with stack:

```
#0  0x000000010e7d5c07 in swift_checkMetadataState ()
#1  0x000000010e7d9a17 in checkTransitiveCompleteness(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)::$_18::operator()(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*) const ()
#2  0x000000010e7d97ac in bool findAnyTransitiveMetadata<checkTransitiveCompleteness(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)::$_18&>(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, checkTransitiveCompleteness(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)::$_18&) ()
#3  0x000000010e7d96a6 in checkTransitiveCompleteness(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*) ()
#4  0x000000010e7da278 in swift::MetadataCacheEntryBase<(anonymous namespace)::SingletonMetadataCacheEntry, int>::doInitialization(swift::ConcurrencyControl&, swift::MetadataCompletionQueueEntry*, swift::MetadataRequest) ()
#5  0x000000010e7d0078 in swift_getSingletonMetadata ()
#6  0x000000010b3bb9b8 in type metadata accessor for MainScheduler ()
#7  0x000000010af4b1c5 in static RxSchedulers.mainScheduler.getter
```

What is the possible way to fix this crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `App` module has two `RxSwift` dependencies that conflicts with each other. The first one is a transitive dependency from `Core.framework` and the second one is inside `App` module. It causes this crash.

Another sign that you have problems with two same dependencies could be warnings on the 
application start. Like this one:

```
objc[8296]: Class _TtC7RxSwiftP33_AB3B9E8806A71B46FB498A7594F5E0D919AnonymousDisposable is implemented in both /Users/andrey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dypyskhwoifkwagjjvtjblqppdnd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Core.framework/Core (0x10e092400) and /Users/andrey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/53D234F9-F917-46BA-B376-F28BA905EE9D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D4C69694-8515-44CF-B077-0CB3256D1F84/App.app/App (0x10bf95430). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

For this case possible fix is to remove `RxSwift` dependency from `App` module. It doesn't broke code because `RxSwift` is transitive dependency and will be available inside `App` module.

Comment: Is this correct? If you don't specify dependency in `App` then you shouldn't use RxSwift in `App`. You will be able to thanks to the transitive dependency, but how should you know if some 3rd party is using `RxSwift` for some internal things? You wanna use it in your app so I'd just add RxSwift dependency to App and it should not break I believe. If it does, SPM would be unusable for for dependency management.